# SQL Server - Loop ignore last Union

Tags: sql-server

I need a query to run through a loop, but I want to union the results. How do I ignore the last union from my query?

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @Initialvalue INT; 
DECLARE @MaxValue INT; 
SET @Initialvalue = 1; 
SET @MaxValue = 6; 

WHILE @Initialvalue < @MaxValue 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max) 

      SET @SQL = 
      'SELECT  SerialNo,( SELECT MAX(EPOCH) as Epoch FROM [' 
      + (SELECT serialno 
         FROM   (SELECT [pointnumber], 
                        [pointtype], 
                        Row_number() OVER (partition BY [pointtype] ORDER BY PC.id) AS rn, 
                        IC.serialno 
                 FROM   [TBP].[dbo].[pointconfig] PC 
                        INNER JOIN [ipiconfig] IC 
                                ON IC.sensorname = PC.pointnumber 
                 WHERE  active = 1 
                        AND [pointtype] = 'IPI') A 
         WHERE  rn = @Initialvalue) 
      + 
']) FROM (SELECT [PointNumber],[PointType],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PointType] ORDER BY PC.ID) AS rn,IC.SerialNo FROM [TBP].[dbo].[PointConfig] PC INNER JOIN [IPIConfig] IC on IC.SensorName = PC.PointNumber WHERE Active = 1 and [PointType] = ''IPI'') A WHERE rn = '
           + Char(39) 
           + Cast(@Initialvalue AS VARCHAR(5)) 
           + Char(39) + ' UNION ALL ' 
    SET @Initialvalue = @Initialvalue + 1; 
    EXEC ( @SQL )  
END
```

If I print **(@SQL)**, this is the printed query:

```
SELECT  SerialNo,( SELECT MAX(EPOCH) as Epoch FROM [8624]) FROM (SELECT [PointNumber],[PointType],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PointType] ORDER BY PC.ID) AS rn,IC.SerialNo FROM [TBP].[dbo].[PointConfig] PC INNER JOIN [IPIConfig] IC on IC.SensorName = PC.PointNumber WHERE Active = 1 and [PointType] = 'IPI') A WHERE rn = '1' UNION ALL 
SELECT  SerialNo,( SELECT MAX(EPOCH) as Epoch FROM [8696]) FROM (SELECT [PointNumber],[PointType],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PointType] ORDER BY PC.ID) AS rn,IC.SerialNo FROM [TBP].[dbo].[PointConfig] PC INNER JOIN [IPIConfig] IC on IC.SensorName = PC.PointNumber WHERE Active = 1 and [PointType] = 'IPI') A WHERE rn = '2' UNION ALL 
SELECT  SerialNo,( SELECT MAX(EPOCH) as Epoch FROM [8667]) FROM (SELECT [PointNumber],[PointType],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PointType] ORDER BY PC.ID) AS rn,IC.SerialNo FROM [TBP].[dbo].[PointConfig] PC INNER JOIN [IPIConfig] IC on IC.SensorName = PC.PointNumber WHERE Active = 1 and [PointType] = 'IPI') A WHERE rn = '3' UNION ALL 
SELECT  SerialNo,( SELECT MAX(EPOCH) as Epoch FROM [8523]) FROM (SELECT [PointNumber],[PointType],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PointType] ORDER BY PC.ID) AS rn,IC.SerialNo FROM [TBP].[dbo].[PointConfig] PC INNER JOIN [IPIConfig] IC on IC.SensorName = PC.PointNumber WHERE Active = 1 and [PointType] = 'IPI') A WHERE rn = '4' UNION ALL 
SELECT  SerialNo,( SELECT MAX(EPOCH) as Epoch FROM [8678]) FROM (SELECT [PointNumber],[PointType],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PointType] ORDER BY PC.ID) AS rn,IC.SerialNo FROM [TBP].[dbo].[PointConfig] PC INNER JOIN [IPIConfig] IC on IC.SensorName = PC.PointNumber WHERE Active = 1 and [PointType] = 'IPI') A WHERE rn = '5' UNION ALL
```

How do I remove the UNION ALL on the final query from the loop?

Comment: Try with `SUBSTRING` from 1 to `LEN(@SQL) - LEN (' UNION ALL')`

Comment: Or conditionally concatenate the `'UNION ALL'` if `@InitialValue` isn't `@MaxValue - 1`

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me an example using my query?